TImber 2.0 Errors
I'm trying to upgrade to Timber 2.x and keep running into errors with template locations.
I switched from Timber::$locations[] =  to using the timber/locations filter; At first it didn't like adding a string to $paths, so they're index 0 arrays, but now I'm getting:
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in timber/timber/src/Loader.php on line 289.
Here's a dump of my $paths (with the full local path omitted):
array (size=9)
  '__main__' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string 'theme-child/views' (length=87)
      1 => string 'theme/views' (length=76)
      2 => string 'theme-child/' (length=82)
      3 => string 'theme-child/views/' (length=88)
      4 => string 'theme/' (length=71)
      5 => string 'theme/views/' (length=77)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'mu-plugins/my-libutils/views' (length=84)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'plugins/my-content-block/views' (length=86)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'plugins/my-item-scheduling/views' (length=88)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'plugins/my-location/views' (length=81)

